# RegionalSettings.TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime will always return 01/01/0001 00:00:00

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, regional-settings

I have the following CSOM code inside my C# console application:-

```
var regionalSettings = context.Web.RegionalSettings;
var localDueDate = regionalSettings.TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime(itemversion.Created).Value;
```

but the localDueDate will always be equal to `01/01/0001 00:00:00`.. my site collection regional setting is :-

[image]

so i though the above code will add 4 hours to the DateTime.. so can anyone advice what is wrong with my code? in my case the `itemversion.Created` equal `14/10/2020 13:14:11`, but  `var localDueDate = regionalSettings.TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime(itemversion.Created).Value;` will return `01/01/0001 00:00:00`!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`01/01/0001 00:00:00` is a blank date. You need to add `context.ExecuteQuery()` after `regionalSettings.TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime(itemversion.Created).Value` to submit the convertion operation.

```
        // timezone
        var spTimeZone = context.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone;            

        //context.Load(spTimeZone);            
        //context.ExecuteQuery();

        //Console.WriteLine(spTimeZone.Description);


        var orginaldate = DateTime.ParseExact("14/10/2020 13:14:11","dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);          
       
        ClientResult<DateTime> cr = spTimeZone.UTCToLocalTime(orginaldate);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(cr.Value);
```